# Find number of elements that have class with webdriver, cucumber, and meteor

Tags: selenium, meteor, webdriver, cucumber

Basically, in the documenation on webdriverIO that I've found, the object `By` is used. I can't seem to find this object in world or browser, and am in general just confused by how to find a set of elements by their class.

My world file looks like this

```
(function () {
  'use strict';
  module.exports = function () {
    var helper = this;
    this.World = function (callback) {
      var world = helper.world = this;

      // set the app URL
      world.mirrorUrl = Package['xolvio:cucumber'].cucumber.mirror.rootUrl;
      Package['xolvio:webdriver'].wdio.getGhostDriver(function (browser) {
        world.browser = browser;
        browser.call(callback);
      }); 
    };
  };
})();
```

Browser and World both do not seem to have the `By` object mentioned by webdriverIO documentation.  Any idea where I would find it, or how to correctly count all elements with a given class?